# Where can I ask Docker troubleshooting questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69433307/docker-container-loses-internet-connection-until-host-os-restart) on Stack Overflow, and it was closed as "not about programming or software development".

The question is about troubleshooting a Docker connectivity issue. Where can I post it instead? Maybe *[Super User](https://superuser.com/tour)*, *[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/tour)*, or something else?

Comment: All of those seem vaguely suitable. With Windows underneath, perhaps not [unix.se]